# Sending eml mime message attach a dat file

Tags: java, email, mime, jakarta-mail

I am sending an email by loading eml file to a mime like this:

```
         InputStream is = new FileInputStream("c:\\Temp\\test.eml");
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session,is);
```

I noticed that the received email comes with .dat file attached.

Why is this happening? how can i the eml without the .dat file?

Comment: Maybe there's a .dat attachment in the .eml file, if not, it may is added by your mail server (provider)?